# Do I need FIS-based switching for Linux software RAID when *not* using a port multiplier?

Tags: linux, raid

I'm planning to build a home NAS with an ASRock AM1H-ITX with four S-ATA disks.

According to the manual the board features two S-ATA controllers:

```
2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s Connectors by AMD AM1 Series Socket 25W Quad-Core APU, support NCQ, AHCI and Hot Plug
2 x SATA3 6.0 Gb/s Connectors by ASMedia ASM1061, support NCQ, AHCI and Hot Plug
```

It seems the ASMedia ASM1061 controller doesn't support "FIS-based switching", but I don't fully understand if this is a problem if I'm **not** using a port multiplier?

I will connect four WD RED WD30EFRX 3TB S-ATA 6 drives to those ports and use them with a Linux software RAID.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your assumption that, if you are not using a port multiplier, then lack of support for FIS-based switching is not applicable to your scenario.